# Closure of a Set

Tags: general-topology

If $A=[1,2]$, then it's closure is $[1,2]$. Why is this true?

My understanding is that closure A is the set containing element $x\in A$ such that for all open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, $U\cap A \neq \emptyset$. Thus, if we look at the end point say 2 there will only be a "half" neighborhood at any given point of time as there will be nothing to the right of 2. So, 2 shouldn't be in the closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're missing is that we are taking the closure of $[1, 2]$ *in* $\mathbb{R}$. It does not make sense to talk about the closure of a set without regarding it as a subset of some universal set.

The closure of $A = [1, 2]$, is the collection of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any neighbourhood $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ of $x$, $A \cap U \neq \emptyset$. The important point is that $U$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ as an element of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take an open interval containing $2$ say $U=(a,b)$. Now $U\cap A=(a,2]\neq\emptyset$ so there is no problem there.

Comment: If you take an open interval an open interval containing 2, it will have to be of this form (a,2] which is not really open always and also your $b<2$ if you take any other and hence it will not contain $2$.

Comment: No. If you want to take an open interval containing two it has to be of the form $(a,b)$ with (EDIT) $a<2<b$... think about it. $(a,2]$ is simply not open (always??).

Comment: How can the open interval be of this form:$a>2>b$? Shouldn't the inequalities be reversed?

Comment: They should of course apologies.

Comment: If that is true then you can never find a $b$ such that $b>2$. Because 2 is the largest element in the set

Comment: Michael above addresses this issue.